# Get list of products that don't have a specific taxonomy in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin, product

I've hit an issue trying to find out what products are missing suppliers on a website with tens of thousands of products.

I need an MySQL query to determine which products are missing the taxonomy "suppliers" through phpmyadmin.

So far I've pieced this together from various answers:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts wp
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wm ON (wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`)
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON (wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`)
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON (wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`)
AND wtt.`taxonomy` = 'suppliers'
WHERE post_type = 'product'
GROUP BY wp.ID
```

I've tried numerous things and cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with you query is that you are not excluding product that has `suppliers` that that product has some other attributes, so you can use `NOT EXIST` or `NOT IN`, I have written the query using `NOT EXIST`.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts wp
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wm ON wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`
WHERE post_type = 'product'
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT `object_id`
     FROM `wp_term_relationships` AS wtr_inner 
     WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` IN
         (SELECT term_taxonomy_id
          FROM `wp_term_taxonomy`
          WHERE `taxonomy` = 'suppliers')
       AND wtr.object_id = wtr_inner.object_id )
GROUP BY wp.ID
```

Another version which will be a bit faster if you know all the `suppliers` `term_taxonomy_id` So you can modify the above query as

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts wp
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wm ON wm.`post_id` = wp.`ID`
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON (wp.`ID` = wtr.`object_id`)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.`term_taxonomy_id` = wtt.`term_taxonomy_id`
INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.`term_id` = wtt.`term_id`
WHERE post_type = 'product'
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT `object_id`
     FROM `wp_term_relationships` AS wtr_inner 
     WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` IN (27,28,29) -- replace it will all suppliers term_taxonomy_id
       AND wtr.object_id = wtr_inner.object_id )
GROUP BY wp.ID
```

Hope this helps!